# NSData null when load file from document directory

Tags: ios, nsdata

```
NSString *mp3FileName = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                  NSUserDomainMask,
                                                                  YES) lastObject]
                             stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"spring123.mp3"];
     NSLog(@"mp3 data %@",mp3FileName);

    NSData *mp3Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:mp3FileName];
    NSLog(@"mp3 data %@",mp3Data);
```

This is giving me in log : mp3 data <>

What is the mistake done by me ?

What to do to convert this file into `NSData` ? I want to send this in Email.

Comment: 1. Check if mp3 file path is correct. 2. Deserializing a large object can take some time

Comment: where is your file is main bundle or assets.

Comment: i was write file from bundle to document directory and getting it back Done,file name is there but size is 0 so it was getting null. then use dispatch_async and problem solved, thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to check the file exist at path

```
BOOL isFileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
```

if yes then only dataWithContentsOfFile: will create and returns the data object otherwise it returns nil.